# Refetch/Reload data in the component after edit a form in a sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component call startpage and a sidenav component to add/edit item to startpage. Both comoponents have selectors on app.component.html. I want to reload the data of the startpage component after I add/edit the item in sidenav component. 
I have use the navigation on router, use the `ngOnInit` but nothing happen.
So what can I do to solve my problem?

*Note: The data I put in startpage is shown in `mat-grid-list` or `mat-table` (I have a `mat-button-toggle` to change the way to show)

Comment: Can you put the codes here or provide a slackblitz demo for your issue? Slackblitz would be better

Comment: I'm working to upload the code on this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wq3sm4. Wait for a moment

Comment: I have uploaded the code related, I don't know whether it's enough so if you need more. Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a service like bellow sample code. I will give you a example so then hope you will able to use that according to your requirement.

First create a service like bellow:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
subject$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }

 refreshData() {
   this.subject$.next();
 }
}
```

Then in your `EventypeSidenavComponent` use it like:

```typescript
export class EventypeSidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  edit() {
    this.dataService.refreshData();
  }
}
```

and then from `StartpageComponent` you have to use that service like:

```typescript
export class StartpageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.subject$.subscribe(() => {
       //refresh your  data here
    });
  }

}
```

And also find the [DEMO here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2c15e).

You could able to match this sample according to your requirement.